# How to use MSYS Makefiles in CLion (EAP)?

Tags: cmake, clion

Is it possible to force CLion use `"MSYS Makefiles"` instead of `"MinGW Makefiles"` and how to set it to do so?

Answer (score 1):

CLion currently doesn't support MSYS Makefiles ([CPP-2275](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2275)).

Comment: looks like it's supported now: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/10/clion-2019-3-eap-ninja-cmake-generators/